# How can I compare values in the same column for different rows?

Tags: sql

The sample table I have is (not the actual data I am working on, but something similar):

```
name    fruit   qty

========================

John    apple   1
John    pear    1
John    orange  2
Maggie  apple   2
Maggie  pear    2
Maggie  pear    2
Sam     apple   3
Sam     pear    1
Sam     orange  2
Donny   apple   2
Donny   pear    2
Donny   orange  2
```

I need to select only kids, which have fruit in 1:1:1 ratio, and the number of fruits they have.

In the example above only Donny fulfills the requirements, so the expected result will be:

```
name    fruit_num
=================
Donny   2
```

I tried to go with a more simple solution:

```
select name,sum(qty)/3 num_fruits
from table
group by name
having count(distinct fruit)=3 and sum(qty)%3=0
```

But that apparently brings some accidental results of kids (Sam in this case) who have 3 distinct fruits and their total number mod 3 is 0, but the ration is off.

I can not think of any other elegant solution and apparently have to compare int of fruits for each kid, but I cannot find an appropriate way of doing that.

Any insight or assistance will be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sum(fruit)` makes no sense. You can't apply `sum()` on a string value - that query won't even run. Did you mean `sum(qty)`?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes! My bad, of course, this is sum(qty) and count(fruit)

Comment: @jarlh in the example above only Donny fulfills the requirements, so the expected result will be:
`Donny | 2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same `qty` for each fruit, then you can use:

```
select f.name, count(distinct fruit) as num_fruits, sum(qty) as total_qty
from fruit f
group by f.name
having count(*) = count(distinct fruit) and  -- one row per fruit
       max(qty) = min(qty);
```

You may need to aggregate first by fruit, if you want to select someone like:

```
Gordon  apple   2
Gordon  pear    1
Gordon  pear    1
```

Then:

```
select f.name, count(*) as num_fruits, sum(qty) as total_qty
from (select f.name, f.fruit, sum(qty) as qty
      from fruit f
      group by f.name, f.fruit
     ) f
group by f.name
having max(qty) = min(qty);
```